# NodeMCU WDT reset

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, watchdog

I have a NodeMCU board that is reset after about 3 seconds of booting up.  I do not have any external caps or resistors attached to my board as other posts have suggested.  I tried several of these methods with no luck.  I have attached my code below along with the output of the serial monitor.  I am uploading code with the Arduino IDE @115200 baud (80mHz) with 4M (3M SPIFFS).

Terminal output:

```
tai
chx2d
csum 0x2d
v60000318
~ld
�� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
�� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� �������������to Hardy
.....
Attempting MQTT connection...connected
Adafruit MPR121 Capacitive Touch sensor test

Soft WDT reset

ctx: cont 
sp: 3ffef550 end: 3ffef7e0 offset: 01b0

>>>stack>>>
3ffef700:  00003a97 00000001 00000002 00000001  
3ffef710:  3ffee5d6 00000150 00000004 4020120c  
3ffef720:  3ffee5d6 0000005a 00000004 402013ca  
3ffef730:  00000001 00000000 00000004 40201300  
3ffef740:  0000005a 000d0462 3ffee630 3ffee7b0  
3ffef750:  0000005d 3ffee594 00000001 40202c5c  
3ffef760:  0000005d 3ffee594 3ffee5a0 40202c87  
3ffef770:  4020153a 00000001 3ffee5a0 4020408b  
3ffef780:  3fffdad0 0000005a 3ffee594 402040db  
3ffef790:  3fffdad0 3ffee4c0 3ffee784 40202a2b  
3ffef7a0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 40204ce8  
3ffef7b0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3ffef7c0:  feefeffe 00000000 3ffee7a9 40204b18  
3ffef7d0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffee7c0 40100718  
<<<stack<<<
������
```

Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "Adafruit_MPR121.h"

int led1 = D6;
int led2 = D3;

const char* inTopic = "/home/room1/switch1/in";
const char* outTopic = "/home/room1/switch1/out";

const char* ssid = "Hardy";
const char* password = "*****";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.199";

uint16_t lasttouched = 0;
uint16_t currtouched = 0;

Adafruit_MPR121 cap = Adafruit_MPR121();

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);

  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  client.subscribe(inTopic);

  Serial.println("Connecting to " + (String)ssid);
  setup_wifi();

  reconnect();

  Serial.println("Adafruit MPR121 Capacitive Touch sensor test"); 

  if (!cap.begin(0x5A)) {
    Serial.println("MPR121 not found, check wiring?");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("MPR121 found!");
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

  client.loop();  //Check for updated commands on topic
  checkTouches(); //See if buttons were pressed

  //delay(100);
}

void checkTouches() {
  currtouched = cap.touched();

  if ((currtouched & _BV(0)) && !(lasttouched & _BV(0)) ) {
    publishCommand(outTopic, 0);
  }
  if ((currtouched & _BV(1)) && !(lasttouched & _BV(1)) ) {
    publishCommand(outTopic, 1);
  }

  lasttouched = currtouched;
}

void publishCommand(String topic,float topic_val){
    Serial.print("Newest topic " + topic + " value:");
    Serial.println(String(topic_val).c_str());
    client.publish(topic.c_str(), String(topic_val).c_str(), true);
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");

  int value = (int) payload[0];
  value -= 48;  //For byte to int conversion
  Serial.println(value);

  if (value == 0) {  //Switch 1
    //temp
    analogWrite(led1, 0);
    /*
    if((char)payload[1] == '0') {  //LED off
      analogWrite(led1, 0);
    }
    else if((char)payload[1] == '1') {  //LED on
      analogWrite(led1, 200);
    }
    else if((char)payload[1] == '2') {  //LED dimmed for night mode
      analogWrite(led1, 100);
    }
    */
  }
  if(value == 1) {  //Switch 2
    //temp
    analogWrite(led1, 255);
    /*
    if((char)payload[1] == '0') {  //LED off
      analogWrite(led1, 0);
    }
    else if((char)payload[1] == '1') {  //LED on
      analogWrite(led1, 200);
    }
    else if((char)payload[1] == '2') {  //LED dimmed for night mode
      analogWrite(led1, 100);
    }
    */
  }


}

void setup_wifi() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("WiFi connected at " + WiFi.localIP());
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe(inTopic);
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect `while (1);` triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

```
delay(5000);
```

I don't think you can put long delays in code on the NodeMCU.  From my experience, long delay calls create just the situation you describe.

Comment: Tried changing the delay to 500ms, but still no luck.  One interesting thing though is I just used almost the exact same code to control a relay today and I had success with that...

Comment: `delay` shouldn't trigger the watchdog reset.

Comment: Then what would?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's not about code,
it's about 3.3v power supply.

A typical phenomenon is

- turn off wifi, it stable.
- turn on wifi, it crash/reboot..